# powershell 'Test-WsMan' is not recognized on Macos 23.2.0

Tags: macos, powershell

When I run the working script I get this

```
Line |
  17 |  if ( -not (Test-WsMan $Computer -erroraction silentlycontinue)) {
     |             ~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Test-WsMan' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function,
     | script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
     | if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Installed powershell on mac this way

- brew install powershell
- brew install openssl
- pwsh
- Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet
- Install-Module -Name PSWSMan
- sudo pwsh -Command 'Install-WSMan'

```
$PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.4.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.4.1
OS                             Darwin 23.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.2.0: Wed…
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: Test-Wsman returns an XmlElement and you cannot use '-not' on an XmlElement.  See Output : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/test-wsman?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: @jdweng, yes you can: try `-not [xml] '<xml/>'`, which is `$false`, whereas `-not $null` is `$true`, so the test in this question works as intended _if_ the `Test-WsMan` cmdlet is present, and its _absence_ is what this question is really about (Mathias' answer explains that and why it is available _on Windows only_). Leaving aside that your specific comment here is _fundamentally_ incorrect, it is generally advisable to explicitly point out when a comment constitutes an _aside_, i.e. when it provides information that is not directly relevant to solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the [module documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/?view=powershell-7.4):

> This module is only available on the Windows platform.

It wouldn't help you on MacOS anyway, as it relies on a bunch of [WinRM-specific APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_winrm/) - it's *not* a general-purpose WS-Management module despite what the name implies